# Jquery If something !=null, give 'else' true also

Tags: jquery, class, if-statement, prefix

I need to get class name from body tag which starts with "title-", and then add that class suffix to H1 which has class "title" . And if there is no class with prefix "title-", H1 should have class "style-default".

"title-style1" - this body class changes it's suffix (style1), and also place in array, so calculating order can't help.

```
<body  class="first something title-style1 last">

    <h2 class="title"> John Doe</h2>
    <!-- need to get this:-->
    <h2 class="title style1"> John Doe</h2>
    <!-- but I'mg getting  this:-->
    <h2 class="title style1 style-default"> John Doe</h2>
    <!-- this is just some other title-->
    <h2 class="style2"> John Malkovich</h2>

</body>
```

I managed to get wanted suffix, but can't put "style-default" properly. Probably some "if else" mistake.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var classes = $("body").attr('class').split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    // finding classes starting with title-
    var $matches = /^title\-(.+)/.exec(classes[i]);
        if ($matches != null) {
        $sufix = $matches[1];
            $(".title").addClass($sufix);      
        }
        else {
              // this also add class to every match ?
          $('.title').addClass('style-default');
        }
    }
});
```

Here'a a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/lima_fil/xz9bA/60/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the `if-else` statement for every class of body tag. So, unless `<body>` tag has just a single class, you will always find some class that isn't `title-*`.

You should modify your code so that you'll add `style-default` class only after the `for` loop. Something like this:

```
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    // finding classes starting with title-
    var $matches = /^title\-(.+)/.exec(classes[i]);
    if ($matches != null) {
        $sufix = $matches[1];
        $(".title").addClass($sufix);

        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!found) {
    $('.title').addClass('style-default');
}
```

Also, keep in mind that variables that starts with `$` usually denotes jQuery objects. (Maybe you confused PHP and JS?)

Comment: I started to learn JS a month ago. What is "!found"? Something like "!=" ?

Comment: It's the logical `not` operator. `!found` is equivalent to `found != false`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same result with just css

```
<style>
body.style-style1 h1 {
    color: white;
}
body.style-style2 h1 {
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: There is too many variations for style1, style2, etc. So jQuery is better solution.

Comment: Well that's your opinion ;) I think its strange to add class names for styling purposes after the page is loaded. But I'm glad you got a fix though!